What units for yaw, pitch, and roll are in a CigiBaseViewCtrl packet?
CigiBaseViewCtrl is a class that represents a packet of data sent from a simulation host to an image generator (IG).  The packet contains yaw, pitch, and roll values.  The documentation for the packet does not mention the units of those values.  Is that because the packet itself does not care, and it is up to the host and the IG to agree on the units?
CIGI = Common Image Generator Interface.  I do not have the mojo to create a "cigi" tag.

https://cigi.sourceforge.io/index.php : CIGI home
https://cigi.sourceforge.io/docs/ccl/html/index.html : CIGI Class Library (CCL) home
https://cigi.sourceforge.io/docs/ccl/html/index.html : CCL documentation


Have you tried checking the specification? Especially section 3.4 (labeled Coordinate Systems) seems to hold the information you seek.

Bah. People need to be discouraged from reading the documentation lest they diminish the power of the technological priesthood.

Thanks @Someprogrammerdude for the useful link.  The CIGI Interface Control Document at that link says:  "An entity’s yaw, ψ, is the measure of the angle formed from True North to the entity’s +X axis. This angle is
specified in degrees and is positive clockwise if looking along the +Z axis."

The CIGI Interface Control Document, as mentioned by @Someprogrammerdude, when describing the "orientation of an entity, view, or other object", says that yaw, pitch, and roll are in units of degrees.  For example:

An entity’s yaw, ψ, is the measure of the angle formed from True North to the entity’s +X axis. This angle is
specified in degrees...

